# Login using fingerprint after Windows 8 upgrade

Tags: windows-8, fingerprint

I upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 8. I have installed fingerprint sensor driver and it works properly for my HP DV6-3060EJ. The problem is in the login screen when I swipe screen flickers and doesn't log in.

Comment: What do you mean by "it works properly"? What works properly and how did you check it?

Comment: when i swipe my finger it works and give me the screen of passwords the only problem in the log in screen it does nothing